# hbase hot region request metrics

Tags: hbase

Hbase cluster, from the master, I can see one of the region get a lot more request than others. but I can not see which region in this server is hotter, the reqest count is only report on the region server level but not at the region level. I see a jira https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7818 already fixed this. but JMX dump don't see such a value. how do I see this? or any suggestion to get per region read/write requset number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hbase Java Client has provided APIs to get region level load.**
Take the client I'm using which is `1.2.0-cdh5.7.0` for an exmaple, YMMV depends on the version of your `hbase-client`.

```
ClusterStatus clusterStatus = yourHbaseConnection.getAdmin().getClusterStatus();  
Collection<ServerName> servers = clusterStatus.getServers();

for (ServerName serverName : servers) {
    ServerLoad serverLoad = clusterStatus.getLoad(serverName);
    Map<byte[], RegionLoad> regionLoads = serverLoad.getRegionsLoad();

    for (Map.Entry<byte[], RegionLoad> regionLoad : regionLoads.entrySet()) {
        // regionLoad is all you want, contains readRequest, writeRequest etc..
    }
}
```

Parse the content of regionLoad and get what you want.

Comment: awesome! thank much. spend a long time to search in JMX, seems it never get dumped out at region level.